# Environment variable overridden in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, overriding, environment-variables

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and trying to compile someone else's code. The documentation tells me to set the environment variable QTDIR in the command line and then launch VS from that terminal. But the compiler still thinks QTDIR is what it originally was instead of what I specified in the command line.

I've tried to restart the computer and do it again, but the result didn't change. I looked into the project properties, but found nothing that seems to be overriding this variable. And when I clicked the  "Macros>>" button in dialogs such as the editing additional include directories dialog, it says QTDIR is what it was originally. (Weirdly: this happens only to one project in the solution; when I opened the Macros>> from other projects, QTDIR is what I specified in the command line!)

So I was wondering if there is something that can override an environment variable like this in Visual Studio. Thanks!

- Edit: The confusing part is when I looked at the property pages of the projects, under `Common Properties >> User Macros` and there's nothing defined there.

Comment: Okay, so this was a year ago, but I solved this by deleting the cached solution files (kept the real sln file!) and compiling anew. And then I was able to set the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I can only tell you about VS 2010, but in that one, macros can be defined on a per-project basis in `Project Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions`. You might look there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is a user-defined macro for QTDIR in your project that you need to remove.

Try the following:

1) Open your solution in VS2013

2) Open the Property Manager by going to `View >> Other Windows >> Property Manager`

*Now you you'll see a hierarchy of Projects, Configurations, and Property Sheets. The User Macro you need to remove will be set in one of these property sheets (probably the one that ends in .user).*

3) Open each property sheet (one at at time!), and find the QTDIR Macro under `Common Properties >> User Macros`. If it's there, select it and click Remove Macro.

Hope this helps!

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer -- but I forgot to mention I looked at every propersheet and their "User Macros" page there and there's nothing there, which is the confusing part. Sorry about that.